# How to remove after second period in a string using sed

Tags: sed

In my script, have a possible version number: `15.03.2` set to variable `$STRING`. These numbers always change. I want to strip it down to: `15.03` (or whatever it will be next time).

How do I remove everything after the second `.` using `sed`?

Something like:

`$(echo "$STRING" | sed "s/\.^$\.//")`

(I don't know what `^`, `$` and others do, but they look related, so I just guessed.)

Comment: ^ is the beginning and  $ is the end of an input/line. https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Comment: Okay Cyrus, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\.[^.]*//2g' file
```

Remove the second or more occurrence of a period followed by zero or non-period  character(s).

Comment: @EdMorton see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) for details of why the flags `number` and  `g` in the substitution command act as they do for GNU sed.

Comment: I'm very familiar with those flags, I just don't understand why that particular combination is necessary given that regexp. For example, given input of `a.b.c.d` and the regexp `\.[^.]*` the 2nd `.` is between `b` and `c` so the `2` should match the **leftmost longest** matching substring which is `.c.d` so why then do you also need a `g` after it?

Comment: @EdMorton using your example the 2nd matches `.c` the `g` flag then matches any following such regexs, in your case `.d` too. So the combination of `number` and `g` flag, matches from number to the end of the string.

Comment: Ah, right, I was getting confused about what the `[^.]*` would match, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think the better tool here is cut

```
echo '15.03.2' | cut -d . -f -2
```

Comment: Yes it is... :-).

Comment: Yes, a better tool and thanks. But, my question was about sed specifically, just sayin.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo '15.03.2' | sed 's/\([^.]*\.[^.]*\)\..*/\1/'
15.03
```

More generally to skip N periods:

```
$ echo '15.03.2.3.4.5' | sed -E 's/(([^.]*\.){2}[^.]*)\..*/\1/'
15.03.2
$ echo '15.03.2.3.4.5' | sed -E 's/(([^.]*\.){3}[^.]*)\..*/\1/'
15.03.2.3
$ echo '15.03.2.3.4.5' | sed -E 's/(([^.]*\.){4}[^.]*)\..*/\1/'
15.03.2.3.4
```

Comment: thanks for this, it's useful and you will be remembered.